# "Twig_Error_Syntax: The block 'content' has already been defined line"

Tags: theming

I have a block template in Drupal 8. I want to wrap a section element around the block when it is in the right region.

Twig gives me this error.

> Twig_Error_Syntax: The block 'content' has already been defined line

I understand the error, but I don't know how to fix it. Can anyone show me how to fix the code?

```
   {% set block_region_var = block_region %}
   {% if block_region_var == 'footer' %}
     <div{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
       {% block content %}
         {{ content.body }}
       {% endblock %}
     </div>
   {% else %}
     <section id="{{ section_custom_id }}">
       <div{{ attributes.addClass(classes,'container') }}>
         {{ title_suffix }}
         {% block content %}
           {{ content.body }}
         {% endblock %}
       </div>
     </section>
   {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can remove all twig blocks from the template; that is, remove all of these lines:

```
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
```

This defines a [Twig Block](https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tags/block.html), which could be used to extend this template, but this doesn't make sense anymore after you have implemented the condition.

Answer (score 1):

1. Write a block preprocessing function in the .theme file and check the block region as in the following code.

   ```
    function THEMENAME_preprocess_block(&$variables ){
      $region = $variables['elements']['#configuration']['region'];
      if($region == "right"){  // please use specific region value
        $variables['right_region'] = TRUE;
      }
    }
   ```
2. In block.html.twig, verify `right_region` is set to `TRUE`; then, add the  wrapper class.

   ```
   {% if right_region %}
     // Add the wrapper class.
   {% else %}
     //
   {% endif %}
   ```

Answer (score 1):

For future developers who encounter same issue as me. I fixed it like this

```
{% if condition %}
    <div class="simple block">{% block content %}{% endblock %}</div>
{% else %}
    {% include 'extended_block.twig' %}
{% endif %}

// extended_block.twig with a bit different html structure
<div class="something">
    <div class="something2">
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    <div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It'd be something like this:

```
{% set block_region_var = block_region %}
{% if block_region_var == 'footer' %}
   <div{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
       {% block content %}
         {{ content.body }}
       {% endblock %}
   </div>
{% else %}
   <section id="{{ section_custom_id }}">
     <div{{ attributes.addClass(classes,'container') }}>
       {{ title_suffix }}
       {{ block(content) }}
     </div>
   </section>
{% endif %}
```

You really just need to replace any further repetitions of the block with `{{ block(content) }}`.

It's explained in the Twig documentation here: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/functions/block.html

Answer (score 0):

Although this might not exactly fit OP's needs I'd like to highlight Twig [`extends`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/1.x/tags/extends.html) to only override one certain `{% block %}` to get rid of that error.

In Twig blocks are overridable portions. You can simply extend one `{% block %}` in a child template and *everything else in the parent template stays untouched*. You also can simply reference the parent's `{{ content }}` by calling `{{ parent() }}`.

`themes/custom/MYTHEME/templates/paragraph.html.twig`:

```html
{# extends and include paths always start inside Drupal web root #}
{% extends "modules/contrib/paragraphs/templates/paragraph.html.twig" %}

{# And now you only extend the content block of the parent template #}
{% block content %}
  {% if neat_grid %}
    <div class="neat-container">
      <div class="neat-row">
        <div class="inner">
          {{ parent() }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  {% else %}
    {{ parent() }}
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I would do it:

```
{% block content %}
  {% set block_region_var = block_region %}
   {% if block_region_var == 'footer' %}
     <div{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
         {{ content.body }}
     </div>
   {% else %}
     <section id="{{ section_custom_id }}">
       <div{{ attributes.addClass(classes,'container') }}>
         {{ title_suffix }}
           {{ content.body }}
       </div>
     </section>
   {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment becase the reputation. I think the best answer is this:
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/312346/111639

But the first parameter of block function is a string.

The code is:

```
{% set block_region_var = block_region %}
{% if block_region_var == 'footer' %}
   <div{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
       {% block content %}
         {{ content.body }}
       {% endblock %}
   </div>
{% else %}
   <section id="{{ section_custom_id }}">
     <div{{ attributes.addClass(classes,'container') }}>
       {{ title_suffix }}
       {{ block('content') }}
     </div>
   </section>
{% endif %}
```